# TitledBorder border color and width using UIManager

Tags: java, swing, border, uimanager

To change all TitledBorder fonts, I am using UIManager:

```
UIManager.put("TitledBorder.font", new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
```

But what to put to `TitledBorder.border` property to change only the color of the border (or maybe even it's width)?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as using `UIManager` to change all `TitledBorder` font at once, to change `TitledBorder` borders use this function:

```
UIManager.put("TitledBorder.border", new LineBorder(new Color(200,200,200), 1));
```

It will change (set) the border property to the border object passed in a second parameter.
All border types (even the factory class) description can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

This sample passes `LineBorder` object which takes color and width in a constructor just as you asked.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can always specify any property in TitledBorder itself. 
Here is a fully customized example of Swing TitledBorder:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    LineBorder border = new LineBorder ( Color.RED, 3, true );
    TitledBorder tborder = new TitledBorder ( border, "Titled border", TitledBorder.CENTER,
            TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new Font ( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 14 ), Color.BLUE );

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

    JLabel label = new JLabel ( "Some content label" );
    label.setBorder ( BorderFactory
            .createCompoundBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 50, 50, 50, 50 ),
                    BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder ( tborder,
                            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 15, 15, 15, 15 ) ) ) );
    frame.add ( label );

    frame.pack ();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible ( true );
}
```